# How to Decrease CLS (Cumulative Layout Shifts) on a live website?

Tags: performance, web, layout, seo, cls

as we all know Google is rolling out new **Core Web Vitals Update** next month, I am worried about my website [WishesPlus](https://wishesplus.com) which is having a **CLS of 0.33 in Red**, which is bad for rankings on Search Engine. Please help me solve this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cumulative layout shift (CLS) is how much content on the page moves about during the load.

`layout shift score = impact fraction * distance fraction`

**You will see this type of error in PageSpeed Insights**

[image]

**Solution to reduce CLS:**

Simply include width and height attributes in image tags.

`<img src="banner.png" width="256" height="256" alt="verz banner" />`

You can also specify your hight & width dimension on CSS.

`img{ width: 100% height: auto; }`

**Note:** Allow the browser to select what size each image is If you use `srcset` attribute to define images.

You can also use CSS property `object-fit:` contain for a feasible solution with no layout shift.

Answer (score 0):

That's true Cumulative layout shift (CLS) is how much content on the page try to adjust itself till the load complete (Includes HTML, CSS and Javascript).

Tips:

> You can block the javascript files which manage your content layout
> from the browser and see what's the difference between having that and
> blocking that. Whatever difference you find can lead you an increase
> in CLS.

> Use transform property instead of changing the height, width, top,
> right, bottom, or left properties to adjust the content or move
> elements around the port.

If your CLS is below 0.1 it's good and if it's above 0.25 is very bad.